# How to get current user_id in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have table `users`; there are columns `(id, first_name, last_name)`.

I want to display  `last_name||','||first_name` and return `id` for user who is logged in.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you call "`ID`" and what you store in there.

Basically, you have to have a column which contains **username** of user that connects to your Apex application. Let's presume that it is a new column in your table:

```
create table users
  (id          number,
   first_name  varchar2(20),
   last_name   varchar2(20),
   --
   username    varchar2(20)    --> this
  );
```

Then you can reference via `:APP_USER` as

```
select last_name ||', '|| first_name
  from users
  where username = :APP_USER;
```

`:APP_USER` value is what you see in Apex upper right corner, your *username*. If you know that, you can fetch anything you want from the `users` table.

Comment: In addition to what @Littlefoot said, you could create an application item (eg F_FULLNAME), create a computation after authentication to set its value for the entire apex session and then reference it anywhere in the application.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! How can I make this type of computation, can you explain a little to me?

Comment: It's pretty well documented and there are plenty of examples. Lookup "Application Computations" in the docs.